# ASP .NET web api application database error after deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP .NET web api project that connects to MS SQL database using entity framework. The project works fine when ran locally.

I published the project on Azure, created a DB in cloud, also added the necessary tables in the DB. After the website is published, everything seems to be fine until I try to access the controller (Eg: mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/Groups), I get this error:

[image]

I have Enable Migration before publishing my project. When enabling migration, I got an error saying there are two DB: ApplicationDbContext, and myDB (which is where the tables are). So I enabled migration only on myDB. Does the error has anything to do with that?

EDIT:
Here is the connection string from Azure and web.config file:

Web.Config file:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IMS;User Id=userName@xxxxxxxxx;Password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
    <add name="IMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.IMSEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.IMSEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.IMSEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IMS;User Id=userName@xxxxxxxxx;Password=myPassword&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="IMSEntities_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IMS;User ID=userName@xxxxxxxxx;Password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

From Azure (All Settings >> Application Settings >> Connection Strings). The name of the connection string in Azure is `DbConnectionString`

```
Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IMS;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userName@xxxxxxxxx;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Have you added a Data Connection to your Web App using the Azure Portal?

Comment: @James, could you elaborate a little bit on what you mean? I have added my connection string in application settings. Still getting the same error

Comment: Could you provide the connection string in your published `web.config` and the one added to Azure? The entire XML tag, with sensitive parts removed of course!

Comment: @James, I have edited my post with the connection string from Azure and web.config file

Comment: So why doesn't the name of the connection string match any in your config? Typically the connection strings section in Azure is used to override settings, but currently it won't since its name doesn't match any.

Comment: @juunas, Thank you for your response! What should the name be in Azure? Currently it is DbConnectionString. Should I change that to IMSEntities?

Comment: If that's the one you intend to replace, you also have to make sure the format of the connection string matches what EF expects.

Comment: One question mark I have immediately is that your `web.config` connection string is `DefaultConnection` but the Azure one is `DbConnectionString` - is this intended?

Comment: According to your `IMSEntities` connection string, I assumed that you are using Database first to build your Data Entity Model. But when you deploy to Azure, you are trying to use Model First?